# Write to file in SD card in wave shield V3

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, sd-card, audio

I just started tinkering with Arduino. I'm curious to know though, is it possible to read and write to a file stored in the SD card in the Wave shield v3 by Elechouse? I'm able to play files stored in said SD card, but I don't know how I'd go about writing some logs. I'm using an Arduino Mega.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.  The shield is basically a cheap WAV or AD4 (whatever THAT is) playing chip which loads the audio data direct from an (old, small) SD card.  The only control you have is IO pins that emulate pressing the buttons on an MP3 player.